# Difference between adjacent elements - diagonal direction

Tags: matlab, matrix, diagonal

I have a matrix, I =

```
 5     4     3
 9     8     6
 6     3     4
```

How can I calculate differences between adjacent elements in a diagonal directions. I want these outputs(for first and last rows and columns I don't mind padding):

```
  5     4     3
  5     5     6
  2    -3     4
```

and

```
 5     4     3
 9     3     2
 6    -6    -4
```

Comment: you want the answer for how to do it in matlab, or in some other language?

Comment: I want answer for how to do it in MATLAB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by simple indexing (the following assumes zero padding around the edges as in your example):

```
>> diagDiffs = I;
>> diagDiffs(2:end,2:end) = I(2:end,2:end)-I(1:end-1,1:end-1)

diagDiffs =

     5     4     3
     9     3     2
     6    -6    -4

>> antidiagDiffs = I;
>> antidiagDiffs(2:end,1:end-1) = I(2:end,1:end-1)-I(1:end-1,2:end)

antidiagDiffs =

     5     4     3
     5     5     6
    -2    -3     4
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure how to do it syntactically in MATLAB, but in psudocode:

The diagonal adjacent elements for element `i,j` are at positions:

List of elements = `{(i+1,j+1),(i+1,j-1),(i-1,j+1),(i+1,j-1)}`.

Basically, for each element position, find its "list of elements" in both matrices, and subtract. Sorry, I can't give you real code.